# Pose mode isn't working

Tags: pose-mode

i've finished rigging and skinning my character in my blender file...  Now i want to animate my character, but when i try the pose mode, i can't move my bones...  I've tried everything.  I've also noticed my bones are blue when i select them.

You can find the .blend file here:  http://dropcanvas.com/1p1r0

thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Could you mark the tick beside my answer to set it as solved if it solved your problem? To help future users facing the same problem as shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFhXo.png

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the Manipulate Center Points to Off as shown below:
[image]

Now you will be able to rotate your bones as shown below:[image]